# Prove $f$ is a local diffeomorphism

Tags: general-topology, analysis, smooth-manifolds, diffeomorphism

Given the question as below:(apology, I don't know how to format properly yet)

[Question](https://i.stack.imgur.com/p3Cem.png)

I am aware that a map $$f: X \to Y $$

is called a **local diffeomorphism** if

1)$F$ is onto and

2)for every $x \in X$, there exist open neighbourhoods $U$ of $x \in X$ and $V$ of $f(x) \in Y$ such that $$f|_U: U\to V $$ is a diffeomorphism

So my attempt is as followed:

$f(t)= (\cos(t), \sin(t))$

If I consider $f:[0,1] \to S $

i.e., $$f(t) = e^{2{\pi}it}$$

then clearly, $f$ is a differentiable, continuous and onto function in that range.

Hence, $f$ is smooth.(1 is proven)

I am a bit stuck on how to prove 2. My attempt is as follows:

Suppose there exist $X$- a non empty subset of $\mathbb{R}$

Let

$$f: X\to   \mathbb S^1$$

Since $f$ is smooth, meaning for every $x \in X$ there exist an open neighborhood $U$ of $x$ in $\mathbb{R}$ and a smooth map

$$F:U \to \mathbb S^1$$

such that $F(y)=f(y)$ for every $y \in X \cap U$

From then on, I was thinking of using the definition of smooth manifold to create an open nbh $U$ in $X$ and a diffeomorphism to optain a smooth chart, hence $X$ is a locally diffeomorphism.

Is my understanding correct? I'd appreciate for all the help and guidance.

Comment: Where did you see this definition? Surjectivity is not usually part of the definition of local diffeomorphism.

Comment: In any case, whether or not surjectivity is required, your map is not a local diffeomorphism. You're going to have trouble at $0$ and $1$.

Comment: [Linked](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2432378/let-ft-cos-t-sin-t-show-that-f-is-a-local-diffeomorphism).