# Let $f(t) = (\cos t,\sin t)$. Show that $f$ is a local diffeomorphism

Tags: general-topology, functional-analysis, analysis

> Let $f : \mathbb{R} \to S^1$ be the standard map,
>   $f(t) = (\cos t,\sin t)$. Show that $f$ is a local
>   diffeomorphism.

I am really not too sure where to start.  I was thinking along the lines of letting $t$ be an element of $(t+\delta,t-\delta)$

where $\delta$ is greater than zero and less than $\pi$.

Not too sure where to go from here.

Comment: You can easily write down an inverse for $f$.

Comment: Thank you, so I have the function and inverse functions and they are both C^(infinity) as required, so f and f^-1 are both C^(infinity). Just trying to prove the 1-1 and onto for the subset it what I am struggling with a bit.

Comment: Ok, $f^{-1}$ does not really make sense as the inverse will be only a local inverse. In fact, your map may be written as $t \mapsto e^{it}$ so the inverse is $\theta \mapsto -i \log( \theta)$. Of course the point is that $\log$ is not defined as a function, so you need to pick a special determination of the logarithm depending where do you want your inverse to be defined.

Comment: Ok so I am not too sure what you mean that log is not defined as a function,  when you say pick a special determination do you mean a specific θ

Comment: No, $\theta$ is a fixed angle, but for example if we take $\theta = 1$ then $\log(1)$ could be defined as $0, 2\pi, -2 \pi, \dots$ as $\exp(2k \pi) = 1$ for any $k \in \Bbb Z$. In fact, a choice of such a $k \in \Bbb Z$ is exactly a choice of an inverse. A similar but somehow easier example would be to take $f : S^1 \to S^1, z \mapsto z^2$ and try to find an inverse.

Comment: [How to format maths with MathJax.](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference)

Comment: What's the chart you're using for $S^1$?

Comment: [Linked](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2429825/prove-f-is-a-local-diffeomorphism).